# How to stop Wercker from running build on deploy branches

Tags: git, wercker, hugo

**tl;dr How to set up Wercker so that build runs only from `master` branch.**

Hi, I have problem with wercker that i cant seem to solve, I have build that utilizes gulp and I want to build my assets than use hugo to build the site which works fine but i cant seem to get my head around why does build task starts when deploy gets finished.

```
box: node

build:
  steps:
    - npm-install
    - hgen/gulp@0.1.3:
        tasks: build:prod
    - arjen/hugo-build:
        config: config.production.yaml
    - samueldebruyn/minify:
        css: false
        js: false
    - script:
        name: "gitignore"
        code: |-
          cp .deploy.gitignore .gitignore
deploy:
  steps:
    - install-packages:
        packages: git ssh-client
    - lukevivier/gh-pages@0.2.1:
        token: $GIT_TOKEN
        basedir: public
```

It does finish note that i don't want build files in my gh-pages branch so i made inline script that changes .gitignore to the new one, and build does pass but when it finishes it automatically calls build on new branchm, i just want to stop that ?

Here are the images they may help.
[image: Build overview]

And best of all it does exactly what i need it to do but it fails it is really annoying any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ukaric/Site/tree/gh-pages) to the gh-pages branch as you all can see no build files are carried over from master branch.

I just don't want any builds running outside master branch and i cant seem to find out just how to do that.

Managed to fix it by switching to different workflow.

Answer (score 0):

a. The easiest way is to put `gh-pages` to `Ignored branches` in: `your project` -> `workflows` > click on `build` > and fill `Ignore branches`.

b. just delete the default workflow (all steps) and create a new one with `master` branch:
`Start new Workflow` -> `On branch(es):` -> put `master`